# Border radius not showing

Tags: border, css

http://thc-cup.ucoz.com/forum/2-1-1

After you can see, the left has a radius at content background and border, but the left one does not! I managed to get it like the one in the left after adding to the div style: display:inline-block; but that messes the box and moves it under the left block.
Since this is a forum (my link) I can't edit html, but I can edit the CSS of the forum.

Here is the style of those blocks:

```
.postTdInfo { //Left block
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.posttdMessage { //Right block
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 25px;
```

I searched all the day for a solution but can't seem to find one.
Is there any way of changing CSS so that the block accepts border radius?

Comment: "After you can see". You're assuming I'm going to visit a site I don't trust. How about posting the relevant HTML and CSS here, and also creating a jsFiddle example?

Comment: Yeah, there is an awful lot of JavaScript running on that page that I wouldn't trust - and it's hard to understand what the question even means.

Comment: Both elements have border-radius in Firefox/Win7. What browser are you using?

Comment: It looks fine for me as it is showing border-radius both in chrome as well as in firefox..

Comment: I can't see the border radius, not in chrome, not in firefox, only IE seems to get it. Tried on another pc and it looks the same. I will post under a image where you can see what's the problem: http://thc-cup.ucoz.com/Snapshot_2013-02-06_210618.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: my first answer didn't solve the problem.**

The problem is that you're working on a `td` element, which has the `display` property by default set to `table`. Either add `display: block;` to `.posttdMessage`, or, if this causes problems, add another `<div>` element directly inside the table cell and style that with rounded borders instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the job! display:block; was messing up things but <div> with radius inside the table worked.Thanks!

Comment: Manuel, appreciate your answer was over two years ago but I wanted to thank you for this - I was wondering why I couldn't get rounded corners showing in a `th` (within a `thead`/`tr` block) and this explains it - just embed a `div` inside the `th` and it works great!  Thank you sir!

Comment: Thanks, Manuel! My problem was different but your answer lead me to the rigth path.